# How to fix Whatsapp always leaves opened conversation to main chats (contacts) view?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am using redmi note 12 xiaomi MIUI 13

The situation is like this; I open Whatsapp, then open some conversation with anyone. Then if I switch away from Whatsapp, not closing it, only switching to another application, now if I switch back to the Whatsapp again, I expect to see the same opened conversation, but what happens is that Whatsapp always switches from that opened conversation to the main view instead which is the chats view; list of contacts view. Then I have to open the conversation with that contact again and again.

I uninstalled Whatsapp and downloaded it again, the problem solved for few days but continue again!.

How to fix?

Comment: It seems the WhatsApp app was killed in the background. You might find info from [Don't Kill My App!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi) helpful to prevent/reduce that case.